# How much would a swipe down/up move a normal vertical RecyclerView/list?

Tags: android, scroll, adb, swipe, gesture

Suppose I use this command:

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 x1 y2 50
```

How can I know how much pixels will it really scroll?

Is there any way to calculate it?

Comment: is there any particular reason for using `50ms` duration?

Comment: @AlexP. Yes, I think it's the minimal time, but you can set it to "t" if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the `duration` parameter is set to `300ms` for a reason - anything less than that and your `swipe` has a much higher chance to become a `fling` (also depending on the delta of your coordinates) - which will not be precise and/or consistent.

So there is no way to find out how many pixels your specific (i.e. with shorter than recommended duration) command will scroll ahead of time.

Comment: Why can't I calculate for a fling? Also, even if it is 300 , how much would that scroll? Suppose I have a listVew (or RecyclerView) with 1000 rows, each is of 100dp , I would like to know how many rows will it scroll over.

Comment: Once you set the duration long enough for the swipe to become a *drag* it becomes consistent enough that you can assume that it will scroll the exact number of pixels you specify. i.e. `input swipe <x> <y> <x> <y+200> 300` command where `x` and `y` are absolute coordinates of the center of your ListView widget (and it's at least 400 pixels high) will scroll exactly 200 pixels

Comment: It's just that I need to scroll the list all the way to the bottom as fast as possible (yet still go over all rows). I know the number of rows and I know the height of each row. That's why I thought that a fling would be perfect, but you say I can't calculate it well enough to be reliable. Can I do the swipe to any value I wish? Even outside of the screen?