# Adb swipe / scroll

Tags: android, adb

I want scroll an app with `adb`
So, I used this command :

```
adb shell input swipe 100 100 100 1000
```

But, the scroll is never the same.
Sometimes it scrolls 900px and sometimes it scrolls 600px.
How can I have the same number of `px`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296885/1778421

Comment: Yes, I have read this post.
But, even if i execute adb shell input swipe 100 100 100 1000 1000, there is a problem
I want that my screen scroll of exactly 900px for example